# How to catch error response properly in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

i need to catch response body produced by my REST API, which is throwing http error 406 with custom response body, but in my angular, i only can catch the header status which is 'Not Acceptable', i can't get the body, how can i get the body instead of the 'Not Acceptable' string? and i got this error too `TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.` which is i dunno which part that trigger this error. Here is how i do it :

first i create global service class, which is looked like this :

```
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private alertx: AlertService) { }

    post<T>(url: string, body?: any, header?: HttpHeaders, param?: HttpParams): Observable<HttpResponse<T>>{
      return this.http.post<T>(url, body,
        {headers : header ? header : this.headers,
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'json',
        params: param})
        .pipe(catchError(err => {
          const error = err.error?.error_description || err.error?.message || err.statusText;
          console.log(err);
          console.log('here i am');
          return throwError(error);
        }))
        .pipe(timeout(10000), catchError(err => {
          if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
            this.alertx.error('Timeout Exception');
            return throwError('Timeout Exception');
          }
        }))
        .pipe(shareReplay());
  }
```

i tried to console.log the error it just appear string 'Not Acceptable', and it continued by console.log('here i am'); it print out properly, and i can't find where the cause of `TypeError`

here is how i use function above :

```
  requestCancel(data: SelectItem, reasonCancel: string): Observable<any> {
      const request: RequestResponse<SelectItem> = new RequestResponse<SelectItem>(data);
      request.message = reasonCancel;
      return this.rest.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}${endpoint.sales_order.request_cancel}`, request).pipe(map(
          response => {
              return response.body.data;
          }));
  }
```

when i trying to console.log the response, it didn't appear. I think my function stop working in my post function at my global service class, what did i do wrong?

**------------------ UPDATE OF MY CODE --------------------**

i create HttpRequestInterceptor class to handle the error, here is my class :

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  user: UserModel;
  prevUrl: string = '';
  constructor(
    private loginSvc: LoginService, 
    private alertx: AlertService,
    private sharedService: SharedService) {
    this.sharedService.currentUserSubject.subscribe(user => this.user = user);
  }

  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.sharedService.setLoading(true, httpRequest.url);
    return next.handle(httpRequest).pipe(catchError(err => {
      if ([401, 403].includes(err.status) /* && this.user */) {
        // auto logout if 401 or 403 response returned from api
        this.sharedService.setLoading(false, httpRequest.url);
        this.loginSvc.removeLocal();
      }
      this.sharedService.setLoading(false, httpRequest.url);
      const error = err.statusText || err.statusText + ' ' + err.error?.message || err.statusText + ' ' + err.error?.error_description;
      this.alertx.error(error, {autoClose: true});
      return throwError(err.error?.message);
    }))
      .pipe(map<HttpEvent<any>, any>((evt: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this.sharedService.setLoading(false, httpRequest.url);
        }
        return evt;
      }));
  }
}
```

when i console.log my `err.error?.message` i can catch the error properly, then i the value passed to here :

```
    post<T>(url: string, body?: any, header?: HttpHeaders, param?: HttpParams): Observable<HttpResponse<T>>{
      return this.http.post<T>(url, body,
        {headers : header ? header : this.headers,
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'json',
        params: param})
        .pipe(catchError(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return throwError(err);
        }))
        .pipe(timeout(10000), catchError(err => {
          if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
            this.alertx.error('Timeout Exception');
            return throwError('Timeout Exception');
          }
        }))
        .pipe(shareReplay());
  }
```

until there i still can catch the error properly when i `console.log(err)` but when i consume the `post` function, i can't catch the error, and i got error in my browser console. Here is my function :

```
  requestCancel(data: SelectItem, reasonCancel: string): Observable<any> {
      const request: RequestResponse<SelectItem> = new RequestResponse<SelectItem>(data);
      request.message = reasonCancel;
      return this.rest.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}${endpoint.sales_order.request_cancel}`, request).pipe(map(
          response => {
              return response.body.data;
          }))
          .pipe(catchError(err => {
              // i cannot get anything here
              console.log(err);
              return err;
      }));
  }
```

i can't log my error, it doesn't event print anything, i think my function crashed and throw this error instead :

```
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

what did i still missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an interceptor to handle errors in 1 place. It would be more convenient, because you will not have to handle simular scenarios in different services

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap( // or catchError operator
        (event: HttpEvent<any>) => event,
        (error: any) => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (error.status === 406) {
              // do something here
            }
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

And add RequestInterceptor into array of providers of AppModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RequestInterceptor, multi: true }
    ],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: i have tried your answer, but i still can't catch the error properly

Comment: Have you added RequestInterceptor into the array of providers of AppModule? See updated answer

Comment: I tried your answer but It's get wrong error this error message something like "An unexpected server error occurred." But I want to get real error message

Comment: this does not working

Comment: which part doesn't work @FaiZalDong?

Answer (score 0):

As agreed with Timothy's answer, `HttpInterceptor` is convenient to handle error from a single place which provides a way to intercept `HTTP` requests and responses to transform or handle them before passing them along.

There are two use cases that can be implemented in the interceptor.

First, `retry` the `HTTP` call once or multiple times before throwing the error. In some cases, for example, if there is a timeout, better to continue without throwing the exception.

For this, use the `retry` operator from `RxJS` to resubscribe to the observable.

Then check the status of the exception and see if it is a `401` unauthorized error. Then check the status of the exception and see if it is a `406` not acceptable error. With token-based security, try to refresh the token, if required. If this does not work, redirect the user to the login page or else.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, 
  HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse 
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ServerErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          // refresh token
        } 
        else if (error.status === 406) {
          // do something here
        } 
        else {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      })
    );    
  }
}
```

Here you may `retry` once before you check the error status and rethrow the error. Refreshing security tokens is up to you, if required.

Comment: i have tried your solution, but i still can't catch the error when it throwed, i will update my question